Puppeteer PDF-Download show Chrome-Toolbar in downloaded file
I'm trying to download a PDF file using puppeteer, but every time the Google Chrome toolbar appears even though I use the pure PDF download link.
I tried using this code to download the PDF:
public async downloadPdf() {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
            {
                headless: true, args: [
                    '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
            }
        );
        const url = "https://notability.com/n/download/pdf/1_tGACBM45Y8SBARa88w_J/Note%203.%20Oct%202024.pdf"

        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "networkidle2"});

        const pdf = await page.pdf()

        await browser.close();

        return Buffer.from(pdf);
    }

The output looks like this:

But it should look like this:

Is there any way to download just the file without the toolbar?

If you have a .pdf file, why not just download it as a file instead of turning the web's PDF preview view into a PDF?

This question is similar to: How can I download and save a file using the Fetch API? (Node.js). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This looks like a misapplication of browser automation. If you have a raw file URL, simply download the file directly with fetch, which is built into Node:
const fs = require("fs");
const {Readable} = require("stream");
const {finished} = require("stream/promises");

const url =
  "https://notability.com/n/download/pdf/1_tGACBM45Y8SBARa88w_J/Note%203.%20Oct%202024.pdf";
const stream = fs.createWriteStream("output.pdf");
(async () => {
  const {body} = await fetch(url);
  await finished(Readable.fromWeb(body).pipe(stream));
})();

This is a URL drop-in to this code. I'd normally mark this as a dupe but in this case it's potentially useful as a signpost since Puppeteer is often misused for this.
For cases when you need to work through a login flow before accessing the PDF, you can run the fetch from the browser or pull down necessary headers and cookies into Node, copied from the browser fetch format.  This still avoids having to use page.pdf(), which is primarily used to turn HTML views into PDFs. PDFs are already PDFs, so page.pdf() is like taking a screenshot of a jpeg, an absolute last resort for cases when it's impossible to save the actual file directly.
